# Start a letter/email with a minuscule or a majuscule

Tags: capitalization, greetings, letter-writing, salutations

So in German when you write a letter, you start the body with a minuscule letter because the salutation is seen as an interjection, I presume:

> Dear Max,
>
> We just saw [yada, yada, letter]

---

> Dear Max, we just saw [yada, yada, letter]

So, my question is: is it OK to start a letter in English with a lowercase letter, or is that bad style/mechanics/etc? If it's not acceptable, what is the salutation considered as and why do we separate it with a comma if it's not part of the first sentence.

Comment: Generally letters begin with a complete sentence, starting with a capital letter as usual. German rules for spelling and capitalization are completely different from English rules.

Comment: First, in formal letters you are supposed to use a colon with "Dear Max:". A comma is considered informal and I wouldn't be surprised if it was a more recent innovation than the colon. Following colons with capital letters is permitted if the colon applies to more than one sentence, so with a colon the salutation actually makes grammatical sense.

Comment: Capital letters following colons *are* permitted.  Match your subjects and objects, @PeterShor (:

Comment: @DopeGhoti: The subject of that sentence is "following", which is singular. I admit I make lots of mistakes, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: It read to me as though the subject were 'Following colons' (plural) against the verb 'is' (singular), which is what I keyed upon.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: "are" would be correct if "Following" were intended as an adjective describing "colons".  But then, "with capital letters" wouldn't make sense, as colons can't have capital letters.

Comment: And thus, I was Enlightened.

Comment: Just start all your correspondence with 'I' and then you never need to rememeber ;)

Answer (score 4):

Most letters I have read follow the form:

> Dear Max,
>
> We just saw [yada, yada, letter]

If you wanted to use a lowercase letter for the first sentence you type exactly what you have in your second example:

> Dear Max, we just saw [yada, yada, letter]

The important difference is that you would not include the blank line. The following would be incorrect:

> Dear Max,
>
> we just saw [yada, yada, letter]

Comment: blank line --> new line